# Which libraries to use to implement cryptographic functions?

Tags: library, python, cryptography

I am using python3 to implement a Vehicular ad hoc network's solution using cryptography. In python3 I found many cryptographic libraries to implement algorithms such as RSA, AES, etc.

But none about things like Bilinear Pairing, Elliptic Curve Cryptography, Elliptic Curve Logarithm Problem, and many other famous cryptographic algorithms. Does anyone know how to implement these algorithms for further use, or any libraries that I need to implement in Python3?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), [code fragments](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), etc. So could you please **[edit]** your question to focus on those libraries – maybe also mentioning your requirements towards cost and licenses? Thanks!

Comment: See https://github.com/andreacorbellini/ecc for a nice python implementation of elliptic curve cryptography, including ECDH key generation, ECDHE key exchange, and ECDSA signing/verification.